# Update DB using stored procedure and ADO.NET

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlcommand

I think I'm missing an 'USING" statement in my class as I'm getting an error when I try to set the commandType to stored procedure.  When I type 'cmd.CommandType =', Intellisense fails to find the 'CommandType.StoredProcedure (Note: the function is only partly roughed out).  Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LegacyForms.Personal
{
    public partial class FormBuilder : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the DB connection:
            string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssociatedBank2011ConnectionString"];
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);



        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspInsertPersonalAccountApplcation", conn);
        cmd.Commandtype = **get error here!**
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", AcctType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountSubType", AcctSubType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckingOption", CheckOption);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Data;
```

You need to reference `System.Data`.  See the [MSDN Reference for the `CommandType` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx).  Direct quote:

> **Namespace**:  System.Data 
>   **Assembly**:  System.Data (*in System.Data.dll*)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend the *other* `using` statement for your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.  Since they both implement the `IDisposable` interface, you can do the following:

```
string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssociatedBank2011ConnectionString"];
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspInsertPersonalAccountApplcation", conn))
{
    cmd.Commandtype = CommandType.StoreProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", AcctType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountSubType", AcctSubType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckingOption", CheckOption);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

That way, in the case that your code works correctly *or* throws an exception in the using block, your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` will clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In such situations you can press CTRL + . (ctrl + dot) to get a suggestion like do you want to add using System.Data...

P.S. Teach a men to fish ...